# smooth curve of scatter data frame data in R and add confedence interval

Tags: r

I have many data.frame and each one contains many columns. Say my first data.frame col1=a, col2=b,col3=c

I want to plot x-axis=b/a  and y-axis=a. I managed to plot them (scatter plot)

```
plot (dataframe$b/dataframe$a, dataframe$a, xlim=...,ylim=..)
```

Now, I need to get the pattern for the scatter data ( I don't want linear regression as both of x and y are changing). I did use the command `loess(..)` and I was able to show the pattern.

```
lo_smooth<-loess(x,y, f=number, iter=number)
```

How I can add the confidence intervals (CI) to the graph? My goal is to check if two data.frame are within each other CI or not.

Comment: Have a look at the package `ggplot2`, specifically `stat_smooth`. I would think something like `ggplot(dataframe, aes(x= b/a, y= a)) + geom_point() + stat_smooth()` would do the trick

Comment: I have used the following command and it worked. However, how do I join for example 3 ggplots in one plot.                          ggplot(dppm, aes(x= b/a, y= a)) + geom_point() + stat_smooth(method="loess",se=TRUE,level=0.90)+coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 100))

Comment: I've added an answer that addresses this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution that uses your attempt (Well done!) plus your clarification

Some dummy data

```
dppm <- data.frame(a = runif(100, 1, 100), b = runif(100,1, 100))
dppm_2 <- data.frame(a = runif(100, 1, 75), b = runif(100,1,75))
dppm_3 <- data.frame(a = runif(100, 1,50), b = runif(100,1,50))
```

Using reshape2 to melt these data into a single data frame
    library(reshape2)

```
data_list <- list(dppm1 = dppm, dppm2 = dppm_2, dppm3 = dppm_3)
all_data <- melt(data_list, id.vars = c('a','b'))
```

This single data frame has a column `L1` that is the identifier (the name of the list component in `data_list`.

```
head(all_data)
          a        b    L1
## 1 83.202896 36.94026 dppm1
## 2 42.618987 11.23863 dppm1
## 3 29.505029 11.91742 dppm1
## 4 63.569487 59.07395 dppm1
## 5 94.499772 47.32779 dppm1
## 6  4.535389 64.11570 dppm1
```

We can then plot this combined data set and colour by this identifier.
We also set the `fill` for the smooth to the same identifier so that the CIs will be coloured in the same way.

```
ggplot(all_data,aes(x = b/a, y = a, colour = L1)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_smooth(method = "loess", se = TRUE,level = 0.90, aes(fill = L1))+
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 100))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It works perfect. However, I have noticed something strange in the stat_smooth(method = "loess",...). The smooth line is not actually fit correctly within the scattered data. For example the smooth-line for one of the dataframe scatter points, touch the zero, while the scatter data far above the axis. In other words, I feel the method="loess" is not performing well. Any suggestion???